# Fixing macOS Big Sur Finder SIDEBAR width prefs from command line?

Tags: finder, command-line, big-sur, defaults, sidebar

My default sidebar width in Big Sur is too small. While I can click/drag to make folders look wider, **that fix only works for folders that I open**. If any application calls a new window to open - say for picking a file to attach or upload - the default windows that open render differently and my sidebar shortcuts once again can't be fully seen.

When I drill down into those prefs via CLI to change them, there seem to be about a dozen places in the finder's preferences file that mention the sidebar width:

```
defaults read com.apple.finder | grep SidebarWidth
        SidebarWidth = 174;
        SidebarWidth = 221;
        SidebarWidth = 221;
    "FK_SidebarWidth" = 294;
            SidebarWidthTenElevenOrLater = 217;
    NSNavSidebarWidth = 120;
        SidebarWidth = 178;
    SidebarWidth = 260;
        SidebarWidth = 135;
                SidebarWidth = 248;
            SidebarWidth = 0;
        SidebarWidth = 221;
```

I'll spare sharing the entire Finder preferences file as it's ginormous, sooo: I have questions!

1. Am I working with the right preference file?
2. Which of these mentions is the right one?

Thanks, all.

For @pion, here's the full code pull you'd requested:

```
WindowState =     (
        BROw,
                {
            EntryPoint = "file://localhost/Volumes/Mac%20OS%20X%20Install%20DVD/";
            ScrollPosition =             {
                h = 0;
                v = 0;
            };
            ShowToolbar = 0;
            SidebarWidth = 0;
            Target = "file://localhost/Volumes/Mac%20OS%20X%20Install%20DVD/";
            ViewHeight = 420;
            ViewStyle = icnv;
            WindowBounds =             {
                bottom = 590;
                left = 597;
                right = 1122;
                top = 170;
            };
        }
    );
```

Comment: Try `defaults read com.apple.finder SidebarWidth`

Comment: So that clearly works for anything I generate in the Finder @pion. It does NOT work for when the OS or an app opens a window FOR me during an upload process.

Comment: I suspect the `SidebarWidth = 0` entry. Can you share its full context?

Comment: Added above, @pion

Comment: Can you tell me the full defaults path to that property? `WindowState` isn't a root-level node.

Comment: I did in the OP, @pion: just remove the grep! 
`defaults read com.apple.finder` - WARNING: IT'S A VERY LONG PLIST...

Comment: No, I need the path to *that specific* `WindowState` node on your machine.

Comment: Wouldn't know how to provide you that, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can upload all of your Finder defaults to www.PasteBin.com if you feel comfortable and I can figure out the path.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/a8BjV0Sp

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder WindowState && killall Finder
```

**Update:**

Also try

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder NSNavSidebarWidth && killall Finder
```

Comment: nope. that doesn't change the sidebars in the windows which are auto-called by the OS when uploading/downloading something. here's a video that shows what's happening:

https://www.loom.com/share/9bccc3cc0f6147a3acda413aedec2fb6

Comment: Can you run `defaults read com.apple.finder | grep SidebarWidth` again and show the new values?

Comment: ```
        SidebarWidth = 174;
        SidebarWidth = 221;
        SidebarWidth = 221;
    "FK_SidebarWidth" = 293;
            SidebarWidthTenElevenOrLater = 217;
    NSNavSidebarWidth = 120;
        SidebarWidth = 178;
    SidebarWidth = 245;
        SidebarWidth = 135;
                SidebarWidth = 248;
        SidebarWidth = 221;
```

Comment: Fascinating, right?

Comment: Thanks for all the help and research, @pion - you've been very generous with your time to an old sysadmin.

Neither solution addresses the size of the finder window (which might be a part of the problem here in Big Sur) nor the width of the sidebar. Not when any application calls for the Finder to open a window to assist in navigation. I've also restarted to see if that might help but no.

Comment: Annnnnnd, it looks like this might just be a "thing":
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/osx-big-sur-11-1-reverts-size-of-open-save-windows-annoying.2275465/

Comment: Remember that the sidebar width is stored in `.DS_STORE`. To test properly, make sure you open a new Finder window at a location you haven't accessed before. For instance, Right click on the desktop to make a new folder, then double click that folder to open it in a new Finder window. No clue if that will make it work, but at least you will have tested properly!